# Custom post types working in functions.php but not in plugin

Tags: custom-post-types, plugin-development

I want to register a WordPress custom post type. This works perfectly fine in the functions.php, but not in my plugin file. The plugin does work except for registration of the CPT. The code is pretty standard.

Registering the CPT:

```
add_action( 'init', 'produkte_menu' );
function produkte_menu() {
register_post_type( 'produkte',
array(
'labels' => array(
'name' => 'Produkte' ),
'public' => true,
'menu_position' => 4,
'add_new' => '',
'supports' => array( 'title' ),
'taxonomies' => array( '' ),
'has_archive' => false,
'exclude_from_search' => true
)
);
}
function toggle_custom_menu_order(){
return true;
}
```

I don't want the editor for this CPT:

```
add_action('init', 'init_remove_support',100);
function init_remove_support(){
    $post_type = 'produkte';
    remove_post_type_support( $post_type, 'editor');
}
```

Finally, I hide the "add new" button:

```
add_action('admin_menu', 'hide_add_new_custom_type');
function hide_add_new_custom_type()
{
    global $submenu;
    unset($submenu['edit.php?post_type=produkte'][10]);
}
```

I'm stuck here. Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: Shouldn't be a problem. Post the surrounding plugin code.

Comment: For test purposes I deleted any other code but the plugin header. There is nothing else in it.